# Angular split string at pipe and use both strings

Tags: angular, pipe

**Requirement :**
I have a string separated with pipe like this - "some value | other value". I need to split it at pipe and use both the values. So, I am trying to achieve it in the template like below.

```
{{row.full_value | splitDelimiter:'|':'beforeSeparator'}}
{{row.full_value | splitDelimiter:'|':'afterSeparator'}}
```

i am trying to use the following code. Any idea why it's throwing an error?
Thanks in advance for any help :)

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'splitDelimiter'
})
export class SplitDelimiter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value:string, [separator], [firstOrLastValue]):string {
    let splits = value.split(separator);
    if(splits.length > 1) {
        if(firstOrLastValue.toString() == "beforeSeparator") {
            return splits.shift();
        }
        if(firstOrLastValue.toString() == "afterSeparator"){
            return splits.pop();
        }
    } else {
      return 'Null';
    }
  }
}

// usage : 
// {{stringToSeparate | splitDelimiter:'|':'beforeSeparater'}}
```

Comment: Can u explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @pkjha, May I know what error you are getting so we can understand what is causing the particular error

Comment: i have a string " some value | other value". I need to take these two into different cells. so, i am trying to split it, so that i can use both.

Comment: @DeekshaMulgaonkar, sure, the error is "can not read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: Please include the error and location that it is generated in your code, and explain what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: 'firstOrLastValue' is undefined i guess. Can you just console that value and see what output you are getting. If it is undefined just check whether you are correctly passing that particular value

Comment: @DeekshaMulgaonkar, yes, its showing undefined. i have included the template code as well.

Comment: thanks all for your time and attention. This is is answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the parameters correctly in your Pipe. They are not arrays:

```
export class SplitDelimiter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value:string, separator, firstOrLastValue):string {
    let splits = value.split(separator);
    if(splits.length > 1) {
        if(firstOrLastValue === "beforeSeparator") {
            return splits.shift();
        }
        if(firstOrLastValue === "afterSeparator"){
            return splits.pop();
        }
    } else {
      return 'Null';
    }
  }
}
```